# Updating sdo_geometry?

Tags: geoserver, sql, spatial-database, oracle-dbms

I have a table `NEW_TABLE` `ID` and `ORA_GEOMETRY`

where `id = 1` then

```
ORA_GEOMETRY = MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 32638, null, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(462897.8239, 4551252.4903, 462869.6794, 4551237.1391, 462821.0656, 4551321.5734, 462770.4983, 4551381.3337, 462764.7756, 4551388.0969, 462754.1560, 4551377.4776, 462741.7481, 4551365.07, 462741.7481, 4551363.7611, 462741.7474, 4551329.2490, 462764.7750, 4551290.8697, 462808.2715, 4551232.0215, 462821.0646, 4551201.3181, 462803.1544, 4551183.4076, 462757.10, 4551173.1735, 462747.3533, 4551152.4610, 462764.0828, 4551144.0964, 462767.3352, 4551142.4702, 462780.1283, 4551122.0012, 462785.2455, 4551093.8564, 462785.2455, 4551032.4494, 462790.3627, 4550930.1047, 462823.6248, 4550861.0220, 462850.7758, 4550815.7704, 462849.2111, 4550881.4909, 462826.1833, 4551001.7460, 462826.1833, 4551065.7114, 462826.1833, 4551132.2357, 462844.0938, 4551145.0287, 462854.3284, 4551083.6219, 462867.1215, 4550983.8357, 462879.9146, 4550863.5805, 462885.0318, 4550812.4081, 462882.4728, 4550727.9744, 462869.6799, 4550633.3048, 462844.0937, 4550513.0495, 462795.4799, 4550446.5256, 462770.4995, 4550405.3075, 462775.6698, 4550405.3077, 462795.8360, 4550409.5531, 462802.7176, 4550412.9935, 462812.8183, 4550418.0442, 462829.8008, 4550425.4738, 462842.5375, 4550429.7193, 462853.1510, 4550429.7193, 462864.8268, 4550426.5353, 462879.6863, 4550415.9213, 462886.6694, 4550410.2476, 462946.4704, 4550462.0752, 462920.8524, 4550490.0220, 462915.7352, 4550538.6358, 462925.9698, 4550561.6634, 462959.2317, 4550561.6634, 462983.6238, 4550561.6634, 462972.0247, 4550648.6564, 462954.1144, 4550707.5047, 462931.0868, 4550776.5875, 462918.2937, 
4550845.6702, 462897.8247, 4550978.7186, 462897.8247, 4551068.2701, 462897.8247, 4551175.7321, 462897.8239, 4551252.4903))
```

and its draw one polygon

where `id = 2` then

```
ORA_GEOMETRY = MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 32638, null, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(511185.4848, 4522136.2067, 511182.8401, 4522157.3649, 511174.9057, 4522175.8784, 511153.7474, 
4522183.8128, 511145.8131, 4522204.9710, 511151.1026, 4522228.7741, 511156.3922, 4522265.8010, 511161.6818, 4522318.6967, 511160.8519, 4522347.7646, 511140.5235, 4522337.2102, 511118.7925, 4522328.3526, 
511098.2070, 4522310.7624, 511089.6745, 4522286.2932, 511086.4391, 4522234.5278, 511084.9831, 4522191.7471, 511079.9685, 4522163.3504, 511057.3211, 4522130.9970, 511037.9091, 4522127.7617, 511005.5557, 4522134.2324, 
510957.0257, 4522143.9384, 510934.2304, 4522157.3649, 510898.7896, 4522166.5858, 510859.9656, 4522173.0564, 510831.0838, 4522162.6545, 510799.3465, 4522181.1680, 510772.8986, 4522178.5232, 510759.6747, 4522162.6545, 
510743.8060, 4522152.0754, 510725.2925, 4522152.0754, 510709.4238, 4522146.7858, 510690.9103, 4522146.7858, 510704.0644, 4522097.1338, 510691.7281, 4522059.8196, 510675.0416, 4522011.9018, 510643.3042, 4521966.9405, 
510630.0803, 4521943.1374, 510619.5012, 4521911.4001, 510659.1729, 4521935.2031, 510693.5551000010, 4521956.3614, 510735.8716, 4521969.5853, 510786.1225, 4521982.8092, 510839.0182, 4522003.9675, 510899.8482, 4522030.4153, 
510958.0335, 4522046.2840, 511002.9948, 4522046.2840, 511066.4696, 4522046.2840, 511106.1413, 4522059.5079, 511143.1683, 4522085.9558, 511185.4848, 4522136.2067))
```

And this one's turn will draw one polygon.

I want to combine these two lines into one, so that if I look at it I show two polygons where `id = 3`

Comment: You've alread got the ordinate array values. You just need to alter the `SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY`

Answer (score 1):

Use the SDO_AGGR_UNION for that.

```
insert into new_table (id,ora_geometry)
select 3, sdo_aggr_union(sdoaggrtype(ora_geometry,0.0005))
from new_table
where id in (1,2);
```